# issue with template operator= with const parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constants, operator-keyword

This is in c++, using Visual Studio 2019 (haven't tried other compilers).
I want to add a templated operator= method. If the parameter is non-const, it works fine. But if the parameter is const, even if I make a version with a const parameter, it isn't called. Instead, it does a simple shallow copy.

If I use a named function instead of the operator, it works as expected. Similarly, if it's not templated, the operator is called as expected. The combo seems to be the issue.

Here's an example that exhibits the issue.

```
class CTest
{
public:
    int x{};

    CTest() = default;
    CTest(int value) : x(value) {}

    // non-const operator=
    template<class SrcType>void operator=(SrcType& src)
    {
        x = src.x;
    }

    // const operator=
    template<class SrcType>void operator=(const SrcType& src)
    {
        x = src.x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CTest   nonConstSrc{ 3 };
    const CTest constSrc{ 5 };
    CTest result;
    result = nonConstSrc;   // correctly calls non-const operator=
    result = constSrc;      // ? shallow copy, not calling const operator=

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to get it to use my overloaded function? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a non-const version? You are not modifying `src` so one is enough.

Comment: From the viewpoint of your compiler, `nonConstSrc` ist not modified by the assignment call, thus the const version is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your const function template is not called because compiler generated *default copy assignment operator* by default, which has signature `operator=(const CTest&)`. When compiler must choose between non-template function and template one (when both has the same match), the former is preferred. That is why your templated method is not called.

To help compiler to select version you want, add:

```
CTest& operator=(const volatile CTest&) = delete;
```

by above, you disable *normal* operator=, `volatile` here is imporant, without it compiler will complain that `operator=` is disabled. By adding *volatile*, you just make that template version is better matched than *volatile* one.

The rest is not changed:

```
 template<class SrcType> 
 void operator=(SrcType& src)
 {
     x = src.x;
     puts("boom1");
 }

 template<class SrcType>
 void operator=(const SrcType& src) {
     x = src.x;
     puts("boom2");
 }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/94VPMu)

Comment: Deleting the `volatile` copy-assignment is and interesting way of doing this. Sneaky. :-)

Comment: Thanks, rafix, This was it. The volatile keyword was what I was missing to avoid the default copy assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If a class does not have a copy-assignment declared, the compiler will generate one implicitly.

You class does not have a copy-assignment operator, it only has a template assignment operator.

When called with a `const` object the implicitly declared assignment operator is a better match during overload resolution.

The issue here is that we can't delete the implicitly declared assignment operator, since it will then generate a compiler error. We can however write our own assignment operator that forwards to our template.

```
#include <iostream>

class CTest
{
public:
    int x{};

    CTest() = default;
    CTest(int value) : x(value) {}


    CTest(const CTest& v) = delete;
    CTest& operator=(const CTest& v) {
        return operator=<CTest>(v);
    }

    // non-const operator=
    template<class SrcType>CTest& operator=(SrcType& src)
    {
        x = src.x;
        std::cout << "non-const\n";
        return *this;
    }

    template<class SrcType>CTest& operator=(const SrcType& src)
    {
        x = src.x;
        std::cout << "const\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CTest   nonConstSrc{ 3 };
    const CTest constSrc{ 5 };
    CTest result;
    result = nonConstSrc;   // correctly calls non-const operator=
    result = constSrc;      // calls copy-assignment and forwards to template

    return 0;
}
```